# How do I find related rows in Oracle SQL db

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Using a table similar to this:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------+
| CONTRACT_NUMBER | ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER | CUST_ID| |
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------+
| 1               |                     0090 |      789 |
| 1-01            |                     0090 |      654 |
| 1-02            |                     0090 |      123 |
| 2               |                     0093 |      001 |
| 2 -01           |                     0093 |      001 |
| 3               |                     0094 |      666 |
| 4               |                     0095 |      999 |
| 4-01            |                     0095 |      888 |
| 5               |                     0096 |      002 |
| 5-01            |                     0096 |      002 |
| 6               |                     0097 |      555 |
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------+
```

I am trying to sort out any records where there aren't duplicates (i.e. contract_number 3 & 6) and where there are duplicates but have the same cust_id (i.e. contract_numbers 2, 2-01 and 5, 5-01) where the only remaining types of contracts have multiple entries with the same contract number but different cust_ids (i.e. contracts 1,1-01,1-02 and 4, 4-01). i need this to be all sql since there are over 140k records I need to evaluate

Oracle SQL 11g

I haven't made any progress with my code.

Expected results would be this:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+---------+
| CONTRACT_NUMBER | ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER | CUST_ID |
+-----------------+--------------------------+---------+
| 1               |                     0090 |     789 |
| 1-01            |                     0090 |     654 |
| 1-02            |                     0090 |     123 |
| 4               |                     0095 |     999 |
| 4-01            |                     0095 |     888 |
+-----------------+--------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test it online with [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8869ca95e10aec22be09aa5a161e3ebc):

```
WITH
  t AS (
    SELECT '1' AS contract_number, '0090' AS original_contract_number,
           '789' AS cust_id FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1-01',  '0090', '654' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1-02',  '0090', '123' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '2',     '0093', '001' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '2 -01', '0093', '001' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '3',     '0094', '666' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '4',     '0095', '999' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '4-01',  '0095', '888' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5',     '0096', '002' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5-01',  '0096', '002' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6',     '0097', '555' FROM dual
  ),
  a AS (
    SELECT t.*,
      COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY original_contract_number) q
    FROM t
  )
SELECT
  contract_number, original_contract_number, cust_id
FROM a
WHERE q > 1;
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+---------+
| CONTRACT_NUMBER | ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER | CUST_ID |
+-----------------+--------------------------+---------+
| 1-02            |                     0090 |     123 |
| 1-01            |                     0090 |     654 |
| 1               |                     0090 |     789 |
| 4-01            |                     0095 |     888 |
| 4               |                     0095 |     999 |
+-----------------+--------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you want output where contract number is repeated with unique IDs, then you can make use of exists to find out cases where you have contract number having more than one unique IDs, and get the output in this way.

```
 with cte as (
 select '1'     as Contract_No, '0090' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '789' as Cust_ID 
 from dual union all 
 select '1-01'  as Contract_No, '0090' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '654' as Cust_ID 
from dual union all 
select '1-02'  as Contract_No, '0090' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '123' as Cust_ID 
from dual union all 
select '2'     as Contract_No, '0093' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '001' as Cust_ID 
from dual union all 
 select '2 -01' as Contract_No, '0093' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '001' as Cust_ID 
 from dual union all 
 select '3'     as Contract_No, '0094' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '666' as Cust_ID 
 from dual union all 
 select '4'     as Contract_No, '0095' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '999' as Cust_ID 
 from dual union all 
  select '4-01'  as Contract_No, '0095' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '888' as 
  Cust_ID from dual union all 
  select '5'     as Contract_No, '0096' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '002' as 
  Cust_ID from dual union all 
  select '5-01'  as Contract_No, '0096' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '002' as 
  Cust_ID from dual union all 
  select '6'     as Contract_No, '0097' as  ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER, '555' as 
  Cust_ID from dual)
```

Query:

```
 select * from cte  co 
 where   exists (select c1.ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER,   count(distinct c1.cust_ID) 
 DifferentID  from cte c1 
             where c1.ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER = co.ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER 
              group by c1.ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER
              having count(distinct c1.cust_ID) > 1) ;
```

Output:

```
CONTRACT_NO ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER    CUST_ID
       1                    0090        789
       1-01                 0090        654
       1-02                 0090        123
       4                     0095       999
       4-01                  0095       888
```

Answer (score 0):

Below would be one way -

```
select * from MyTable where ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER in (select
ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER from MyTable group by ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER having count(distinct(cust_id))>1)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT
        A.CONTRACT_NUMBER
      , A.ORIGINAL_CONTRACT_NUMBER
      , A.CUST_ID
FROM
        CONTRACT_TABLE A
        INNER JOIN
                (
                        SELECT
                                CONTRACT_NUMBER
                        FROM
                                CONTRACT_TABLE
                        GROUP BY
                                CONTRACT_NUMBER
                        HAVING
                                COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_ID) > 1
                )
                B
                ON
                        A.CONTRACT_NUMBER = B.CONTRACT_NUMBER
ORDER BY
        A.CONTRACT_NUMBER
```